# Windows 7 logo testing

Tags: windows-7, logo-testing

We are currently doing logo testing for Windows 7.
We get it successful, however we face some warnings in test case 7.

Test case 7 warns "Executable c:\program files (x86)\abc.exe failed to shutdown."

Can anybody tell me how does it test ?
How can we avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the tests a couple of more time. Here is what i noticed.

**- Test toolkit tried to open the application 

- Waited for some time and then 

- Sent WM_QUERYENDSESSION & WM_ENDSESSION to all the installed EXEs.
- Wait for the response**

When the test ran earlier, the application window was closed manually. Hence when the test toolkit sent the above two messages, it did not received any reply. This caused the warning message.

In a case where these messages are not handled, falls back to windows default handler. Hence in normal cases, i do not see any problem even if they are not handled.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Test Case 7 is "Verify that the application is restart manager aware". You can find an explanation in [this document from Microsoft](http://download.microsoft.com/download/b/8/0/b806c574-71bc-4bb3-8fa7-c887bb525cec/OEMREADY-v.1.0.docx).

Quoting from the document:

> *In order to pass this test:*
>
> The application must deal
>   appropriately with Shutdown and
>   (optionally) Restart system messages.
>
> Note: The application must be idle and
>   not performing any operations during
>   this test.
>
> **Rationale**
>
> To avoid disrupting a Windows Restart or Shut Down request,
>   an application must close when the
>   system instructs it to do so, and if
>   expected, it must restart
>   automatically.

Also, as of Windows Vista, you now only get about 2 seconds to completely exit your app after receiving the WM_SHUTDOWN message, or else your app will fail the test and get killed by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a warning from the windows shell or a debug statement from your own program?

What is test case 7? What do you mean by successful, being criteria-specific?

We will need more information.

Comment: I think you confused some testing with Windows 7 Logo testing, which is a set of test cases required for Windows Logo Certification, i.e. for gaining the right to use a Windows logo on your product.